# same address for different variables of different functions in c

Tags: c++, c, variables, pointers, memory-address

While printing the address and value of 'X' in function foo1 and the address and value of Y in foo2, why it is showing the same values for both of the functions?

```
#include <stdio.h

void foo1(int xval)
{
  int x;
  x = xval;
  /* print the address and value of x here */
}

void foo2(int dummy)
{
  int y;
  /* print the address and value of y here */
}

int main()
{
  foo1(7);
  foo2(11);
  return 0;
}
```

Output of the program is

`Address of X is: 65518`

Value of X is: 7

`Address of Y is: 65518`

Value of Y is: 7

Comment: [Post real code that will reproduce the error.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The whole idea of a "stack" is that whatever function's running gets to use the memory for local variables, then on return the memory's available for the next function to use.  Consider a stack of plates... you can put another plate on top, or take that top plate off, and if you take a plate off and put another on then the same space/(address/memory) will be occupied by a different plate.

Comment: Does any part of specs or your C book says the address should be different?

Answer (score 1):

It's because they're created on the stack, which is unwound after each function call.  So they *are* created at the same memory address.

Comment: but their *value* should not be same.

Comment: maybe `y` isn't assigned as we can see `x` is.... without the code -- who knows?

Comment: @RakibulHasan The function `foo2` in the question doesn't include an assignment.

Comment: Exactly, without the code, who can post an answer? So don't... the question cannot be answered in its current form.

Comment: Why an upvoted answer to a incomplete question?